# Objective-C rectangular CGPoint to polar CGPoint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgpoint, polar-coordinates

I found the equations to convert an X,Y into radius and angle:

```
x = r*Cos(Q)
y = r*Sin(Q)

r= sqrt(x*x + y*y)
Q = tan^-1(y/x)
```

My problem is that I dont remember what is the syntax for the tan^-1 in objective C. I do not want to get things wrong.

This got me thinking: Why build this from scratch? **Is there a built-in way to convert a given CGPoint in Objective C from polar to rectangular coordinates? Maybe there's some CAAnimation class that can help me with this?**

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atan2.3.html (and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: great, I don't even have to type in the /sign if I use atan2(y,x)

Comment: Right, and it handles 360 degrees without `if` logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the angle use:

```
Q = atan2( y, x );
```

This function will work out the quadrant to give the correct sign of the angle.